# Portable executable DOS header length

Tags: c++, c, windows, machine-code, portable-executable

I've been studying this image for building a portable executable: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKwgd.jpg

The image/walkthrough says the PE header starts at 0x40 (64 in decimal).  However, the hexadecimal dump says the DOS header is 32 bytes long. Is it being packed at 4 bytes for each field?

Looking at the IMAGE_DOS_HEADER in WinNT.h, it doesn't seem to fit either.  It has 16 2-byte fields, one 4-length 2-byte array, one 10-length 2-byte array, and the 4-byte pointer to the PE location.  Any way you look at that it doesn't add up to 64...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, the hexadecimal dump says the DOS header is 32 bytes long.

```
Offset:0x30
00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00-40 00 00 00
```

0x30 + 16 = 0x40 (64).

```
typedef struct _IMAGE_DOS_HEADER
{
                        // Cumulative size:
     WORD e_magic;      // 2
     WORD e_cblp;       // 4
     WORD e_cp;         // 6
     WORD e_crlc;       // 8
     WORD e_cparhdr;    // 10
     WORD e_minalloc;   // 12
     WORD e_maxalloc;   // 14
     WORD e_ss;         // 16
     WORD e_sp;         // 18
     WORD e_csum;       // 20
     WORD e_ip;         // 22
     WORD e_cs;         // 24
     WORD e_lfarlc;     // 26
     WORD e_ovno;       // 28
     WORD e_res[4];     // 36
     WORD e_oemid;      // 38
     WORD e_oeminfo;    // 40
     WORD e_res2[10];   // 60
     LONG e_lfanew;     // 64
} IMAGE_DOS_HEADER, *PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER;
```

> It has 16 2-byte fields, one 4-length 2-byte array, one 10-length 2-byte array, and the 4-byte pointer to the PE location. Any way you look at that it doesn't add up to 64...

```
  (16 * 2) = 32
  (4  * 2) = 8
  (10 * 2) = 20
+            4
------------------
             64
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm retarded.  Also why does the image/walkthrough only show 32 bytes of the DOS header?  I don't quite understand that part.

Comment: @RyanBrown It doesn't. The bottom row (which I tried to show above) *starts* at offset 0x30. It's 16 bytes wide, which means it ends at (i.e. the next byte would start at) offset 0x40. So it's 0x40 (64) bytes long.

Comment: @RyanBrown I mean this in the most encouraging way possible: Get *very* comfortable with my answer, and how I confirmed the offset / size of everything. The PE format gets much, much uglier from here.

Comment: So it just implies that bytes 17-48 are all 0s?  I mean the top row is 16 bytes long so it's missing 17-48 right?

Comment: Thanks a ton for helping! I'm just starting to wade through this and I already want to commit suicide...

Comment: Ah, yes, they left those two rows out. Some ellipses (...) would have been nice to stick in between there. They did say the last row started at 0x30 though.  It doesn't necessarily mean they're all zeros, but rather they're [don't care](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t-care_term) values. Meaning, it doesn't matter what they are - the Windows PE loader won't even look at them - it only cares about `e_lfanew`.

Comment: Thanks again!  I'm sure I will have more questions before I'm done with this......